# Which ggplot2 geom should I use?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have a data frame.

```
id <- c(1:5)
count_big <- c(15, 25, 7, 0, 12)
count_small <- c(15, 9, 22, 11, 14)
count_black <- c(7, 12, 5, 2, 6)
count_yellow <- c(2, 0, 7, 4, 3)
count_red <- c(8, 4, 4, 2, 5)
count_blue <- c(5, 9, 6, 1, 7)
count_green <- c(8, 9, 7, 2, 5)
df <- data.frame(id, count_big, count_small, count_black, count_yellow, count_red, count_blue, count_green)
```

How can I display the following in ggplot2 and which geom should I use:

- a breakdown of big and small variable by id
- a breakdown of colors by id

This is just a subset of the data set that has around 1000 rows.

Can I use this df in ggplot2, or do I need to transform it into tidy data with tidyr? (don't know data.table yet)

Comment: See [here](https://flowingdata.com/2009/01/15/flow-chart-shows-you-what-chart-to-use/), [here](http://saedsayad.com/data_mining_map.htm) and [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf) for ideas on which chart type is best to use for your case, then edit your question. Otherwise this question will be closed as "Too broad".

Answer (score 1):

You need to first restructure the data from wide to long with `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- gather(df, var, value, starts_with("count"))

# remove count_
df$var <- sub("count_", "", df$var)

# plot big vs small
df_size <- subset(df, var %in% c("big", "small"))
ggplot(df_size, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())

# same routine for colors
df_color <- subset(df, !(var %in% c("big", "small")))
ggplot(df_color, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

Use `stat = "identity"` to prevent it from doing a row count. `position = position_dodge()` is used to place the bars next to each other rather than stacked.

Comment: I made a mistake, id should be on the y axis and colors on the x axis. If I have 1000 rows and 1000 values for id, maybe a bubble chart would be better to show for which id which color has the highest value. Or maybe some other geom?